# Using booleans in a for loop

Tags: python

So far I have a while loop but I wanted to know how I could check for something while in a for loop.

What I have so far looks something like this:

```
i = 0
found = False
while ((i < len(my_string)) and (not found))
    my_char = my_string[i]
    if my_char in my_set:
        found = True
    elif my_char == 'x':
        i = helper_function(my_string, i)
    else:
        i += 1
return i
```

Comment: So...what's your question exactly?

Comment: FWIW, `break` is a lot nicer than working with `found`... That will _help_ to translate this to a for loop, but I think that really, we need to know what `helper_function` is doing before we can hope to turn this into a loop.  It might not be trivial...

Comment: You just need a ":" after while statement; your code is working!

Comment: The helper function is using the string and the index i to find a certain index of the string. Does that change the answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what helper function is doing, but this would be the basic gist of how the for loop would look

```
i = 0
for char in my_string:
    if my_char in my_set:
        break
    elif my_char == 'x':
        i = helper_function(my_string, i)
    else:
        i += 1
else:
    pass ## put logic here if you need the code to do something if the char wasn't found
return i
```